# Python concurrent action code after calling asynchio await

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am developing a simple media player app in raspberrypi using python. So some songs are requested to play using omxplayer via async function. But after calling the task function in the main, GPIO reading code block does not work before all files are played finished.

```py
async def playthesong():
    songs=[]
    os.chdir("/home/pi/Documents/songs")
    i=0
    for file in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
        songs.append("/home/pi/Documents/songs/"+file)       
        print(songs[0])        
        this_file=songs[i]
        print(file)
        os.system('sudo omxplayer -o local '+ this_file )
        i=i+1

async def playsong():
    os.system('sudo pkill omxplayer')
    nxt=0
    i=0    
    await playthesong()   

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(playsong())
    task
    print('ended')
    task.cancel()
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(13)==0:
            task.cancel()
            os.system('sudo pkill omxplayer')
            print("stopping")

asyncio.run(main())
```

How can i accomplish this with python. Any good at using multithread or any other workaround in async usage ?

Comment: use `await task` in  main function

Comment: Ended up using threads.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution only with asyncio and ended up with Multiple thread system.